# How to Debug and to Fix 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation' for EF 6, Oracle DB, Controller Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, scaffolding

**Edit 2:**

This does *not*  happen when I use `SQL Server`. It only happen when I use `Oracle`. There has been a suggestion to debug or to provide inner exception for this. Yet, since this exception happen during the scaffolding, I can't get the inner exception. Also, I am not sure if we can debug a scaffolding process. If there is anybody who knows how it can be done, please let me know.

---

> Error
>
> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation'

Ok, firstly, [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771404/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-thrown-when-scaffolding) [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879558/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263200/ef-power-tools-beta-2-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724873/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-while-creating-the-con) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001686/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-vb-net) [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417385/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-wpf) [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729111/error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223525/how-to-solve-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-in) [return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576294/application-cant-scaffold-items/24154061#24154061) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437404/asp-net-mvc-4-getting-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invoc) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327885/im-getting-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation).

And thus I learned that this error is not exclusive to creating `Controller scaffolding` in EF 6.

But my case is when I am about to create `Controller Scaffolding` using EF 6 in VS2013, when I create `MVC web application`.

[image]

The option I use is:

```
MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework
```

I use `Oracle Database` and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` `namespace`. Some relevant posts I found are these:

- [Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation thrown when scaffolding a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771404/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-thrown-when-scaffolding)
- [EF Power Tools Beta 2 - exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263200/ef-power-tools-beta-2-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation)
- [Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation- while creating the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724873/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-while-creating-the-con)
- [Scaffolding controller doesn't work with visual studio 2013 update 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910162/scaffolding-controller-doesnt-work-with-visual-studio-2013-update-2)

But none of them talking about the specific case for `Oracle DB`

But since they are talking about any `DB` in general, I nevertheless try some of their solutions, including:

1. Removing all `sections`, `connectionStrings`, and `providers` such that each of them only contain single item:

   ```
    <configSections>
      <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=VSDB;PASSWORD=mypassword;USER ID=myuser&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
   ```
2. Change `DbSet` in the `Context` to `IDBSet`

   ```
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees1 { get; set; }
   ```
3. Use `VS2013 with update 5`.
4. Upgrade to `Entity Framework 6.1.3`
5. Changing the `defaultConnectionFactory` from:

   ```
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
      </defaultConnectionFactory>
    </entityFramework>
   ```

   to

   ```
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
        </parameters>
      </defaultConnectionFactory>
    </entityFramework>
   ```
6. Change `OnModelCreating` event handler from:

   ```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
   ```

   to

   ```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("myschema");
    }
   ```

But none of those works. I still get the same error. I even try *all* of them together and the problem still persists.

I have no more idea on what should be done in this case. Any idea?

**Edit:**

I would also be happy to know if someone can tell me how can I "debug" what's wrong with the scaffolding for my case to get the right solution for my case. I am new with both web programming and Entity framework and really have no idea on what is going on behind the scene which causes the error.

**Edit 2:**

I have tried to isolate the problem by trying to redo the scaffolding by SQL server as suggested by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488397/steve) in the comment and [Squiggle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034004/squiggle) in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28982814#28982814) and I got *no* issue at all. So, the problem must have something to do with Oracle DB settings or (maybe) with the ODP.Net tool which I use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` - whether this is supported by EF.

Comment: Is there any other message or inner exception on the error? Target of an invocation is extremely broad (as you've found).

Comment: @Steve the thing is, I cannot debug the inner exception since it is not a code - but a scaffolding, gotten from creating Controller by `MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework`. If there is any way to debug the inner exception for scaffolding, I would like to know too..

Comment: So you get it when you *create* the controller using Visual Studio tools? Hmm...Obvious question, but have you tried it in a new solution, or a different database access type?

Comment: @Steve "when you create the controller using Visual Studio tools" yes, it is as you say... If you know how to debug such case, I would like to know how. I do it following a lecture shown in the youtube video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pzwRwYlXMw&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v at least in the video, there is not problem when using `SqlClient` default database. As for using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, I have to do some configuration to make it work, and now I am stuck in this issue - not sure what configuration I left out.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to comment out some code in your data context class, e.g. the dbset properties and check whether at some point the error disappears.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the suggestion. I have more or less done it as I try to configure my project but to no avail. Nevertheless, I will try and see again.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the real issue in scaffolding but I want to add help to

> "I would also be happy to know if someone can tell me how can I
>   "debug" what's wrong with the scaffolding for my case to get the right
>   solution for my case. "

Every .net web project has single entry point `Global.asax` that can handle all unhandled exceptions.

Make sure you don't have `customErrors` to `Off`in `Web.config` files.

Just add Application_Error method in Global.asax like:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ ... }
```

Better implementation is available at [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx):

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

  // Get the exception object.
  Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

  // Handle HTTP errors
  if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
  {
    // The Complete Error Handling Example generates
    // some errors using URLs with "NoCatch" in them;
    // ignore these here to simulate what would happen
    // if a global.asax handler were not implemented.
      if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
      return;

    //Redirect HTTP errors to HttpError page
    Server.Transfer("HttpErrorPage.aspx");
  }

  // For other kinds of errors give the user some information
  // but stay on the default page
  Response.Write("<h2>Global Page Error</h2>\n");
  Response.Write(
      "<p>" + exc.Message + "</p>\n");
  Response.Write("Return to the <a href='Default.aspx'>" +
      "Default Page</a>\n");

  // Log the exception and notify system operators
  ExceptionUtility.LogException(exc, "DefaultPage");
  ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(exc);

  // Clear the error from the server
  Server.ClearError();
}
```

You can catch/watch unhandled exception here with all inner exceptions here.
Hope it help in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The most errors occurs due a bad configuration, for instance: connection strings, providers and so on.

In my case figured out that the issue was caused because when installed Oracle client, I clicked to configure it on machine.config so the configuration was taken from there.

Therefore, I deleted the oracle configuration from machine.config , after that the scaffolding working as we expected.

Installed:

1. EF 6 from Nuget
2. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v12.2.1100
3. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntiyFramework v12.2.1100

Removed from machine.config:

```
<!-- <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" /> -->
<!-- <oracle.manageddataaccess.client> -->
    <!-- <version number="4.122.1.0"> -->
      <!-- <settings> -->
        <!-- <setting name="tns_admin" value="c:\oracle64\client\laralal\product\12.2.0\client_1\network\admin" /> -->
      <!-- </settings> -->
    <!-- </version> -->
  <!-- </oracle.manageddataaccess.client> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exact error attempting to scaffold using my oracle db but had no problem scaffolding to my SQL db.  What I found was there was a version # discrepancy in the oracle.manageddataaccess.client sections of the machine.config file versus the web.config file.  So I commented out every section in the machine.config file that contained "oracle.manageddataaccess.client", rebuilt my application and I was able to scaffold my controller and views successfully.